# How to make a x versus on text and math mode?

Tags: math-mode, text

For example, Voltage *X* Current.
X and versus are understandable, but a slightly different X would be better.

Comment: Are you looking for `$\times$`?

Comment: The `X` does not look nice however in most occasions in order to indicate a usual multiplication (cross product of vectors is different, of course), regardless whether is real 'math' or a textual expression of a term

Comment: Do you have a book or paper in mind, where an X-like symbol is used for "versus"? Or is this your own idea? If you show a picture of a page, someone may be able to show the closest thing available in *TeX.

Comment: Yeah, `$\times$`! I don't have a book now, but I believe it is not my own creation haha